# How to sell things that have been brought back from another world

Tags: technology, economy, politics

The MC from our modern world (2016-ish) has been iseikaied to another world of swords and magics. But after the MC defeated the big bad, she declined the invitation to stay in that world and insists to go back to her own world. However, she did received some gifts--including a hundred ingots of room-temperature, atmospheric pressure superconductors that can be manufactured through non-magical means, as well as techniques of mass manufacturing carbon nanotube in however long we want, and a hundred ingots of new alloys that can allow spontaneous water splitting and can be manufactured easily (essentially [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_based_nanogalvanic_alloys#Applications), but 20% cheaper). However, she only has the non-magical production technique of carbon nanotube and doesn't have the metalurgical knowledge to know how the water splitting alloy and superconductor materials can be made using non-magical means. What she does know though, is that all these materials can be made using non-magical means. Through what method, or from whom, can MC benefit from selling the items or the technology to while not revealing to the whole world where these materials and tech come from? It is also necessary that MC won't need to go into hiding or having to every government in the world sending actually military, instead of just one or two spies or assasins, to go after her?

Comment: Given the confusion in answers, probably worth clarifying matters re the superconductors and other items in separate dot points:  which does she just have a quantity of (probably need to define what "large amounts" means, to at least an order of magnitude) and which does she have knowledge of the manufacturing techniques.  If she doesn't have knowledge of the manufacturing technique then no point talking about it, unless you are suggesting that possession of a sample will allow reverse-engineering by specialists on Earth.

Answer (score 4):

## Get rich off minor inventions.

This is step one. You need to get pretty rich off something minor, perhaps body armor with carbon nanotubes. Carbon nanotubes are already something we can create, so with this you can earn a lot of money. It would help if some seed cash was taken back from the isekai world, like a load of gold.

## Bribe local politicians into compliance.

Once you have cash befriend all the local politicians. Go to police balls, schmooze with the rich, you want to get lots of connections with people who matter to resist any heavy handed enemies. You'll need an income stream of at least 1 million a year for this probably.

## Expand outwards to get richer.

Assuming you are the only one who can do this, you can slowly expand to get richer, producing more and more stuff with just carbon nanotubes. You can start lobbying and bribing national politicians. 100 million a year will probably let you start building connections.

You may do some minor inventions after this to expand your income.

## Explode out with some supertech.

Room temperature superconductors are worth trillions. Once you have a couple hundred million as a war chest start making them by using smarter scientists to work out how to make them and locking them up from stealing your tech with restrictive contracts. You can make power lines, very advanced computers and lots of stuff. This is the point where assassins, spies, and super aggressive stuff will be very common, so flash out a lot of cash to people to counter that. Hire a lot of very expensive security as well.

Comment: Carbon nanotubes for body armor? I see where you are coming from. But get this -- a toothbrush only 1/8 the thickness of the usual toothbrush thickness. Wow.

Comment: @Nepene Nep But patent only works if you know how they are made, right? the main character doesn't know how to make the superconductor or alloy, only the carbon nanotube

Comment: I added that you can hire scientists.

Answer (score 1):

**Get investors involved, then go solo**

Looks like your protagonist's problem is that she doesn't have much resources in the modern world, and in order to make money she needs to have money.

First step should be evaluating technologies that she has on hand:

1. Is it something that can be demonstrated an properly impress a potential investor?
2. Is it something that can be manufactured without needing to build new technology base?
3. Is it something that can be easily protected with a patent?

If her "parting gifts chest" contains a technology that meets all 3 requirements above, she is in luck. She should file a cheap and simple Provisional Patent Application (or its equivalent in her jurisdiction) and start looking for investors. After a few possible setbacks, she should be able to team up with professionals who know how to manufacture and market new things. The terms are not going to be necessarily generous to her, she may have less than 20% of interest in the company after a few funding rounds - but this does not matter. After the company would reach [Unicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn_(finance)) status, she would have enough money to do the next things.

Now she would have both the money and necessary business experience to start pulling next things from her gift chest. She should form a private company, set up a research center, hire best lawyers and file for patents. The new company would soon eclipse the earlier unicorn, and her only problem would be the resentment of people who don't like rich entrepreneurs like Bill Gates, Steve Jobs or Elon Musk.

Answer (score 0):

**Go public**

1. Get lawyers to protect your ideas from up and coming tech people.
2. Introduce yourself to an up and coming tech company.
3. With them, patent tech for superconductor production.
4. Make superconductors
5. Take company public.  Pay yourself in stock.
6. Bring out next item.  Make that too.
7. Third item.
8. Sell stock at tremendous profit.
9. Start thinking about the good food and sweet hottie that was back in that magic world.  It has been a while…

Comment: But MC don't know about how to make them though, she know what it is and its function, but she isn't a material scientist

Comment: I thought you said she was given techniques.  Or does she just have a barrel of alien gizmos?

Comment: Very realistic Willk, but I don't expect MC's (Masters of Ceremonies?) that get iseikaied between planets of swords and magic will have the patience to do the paperwork :p

Comment: @Willk She has the technique to make carbon nanotube, but not how to make superconductor or water splitting alloy

Comment: @Goodies sorry, MC means main character